# Get All keys From redis in go

Tags: go, redis, redigo

How to get all keys of Redis in db and store it in list or array in golang using redigo?

```
redisPool := redis.NewPool(func() (redis.Conn, error) {
    con, err := redis.Dial("tcp", *redisAddress)
    con.Do("SELECT", 0)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return con, err
}, *maxConnections)
fmt.Println("Redis Connection Established...!")
con := redisPool.Get()

//defer con.Close()
fmt.Println("Redis Connected...!")
//var sl []string = make([]string, len, cap)
var ab interface{}
ab, errA := con.Do("Keys", "*")
fmt.Println(ab)
fmt.Println(errA)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [Strings](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Strings) function to convert the result to a slice of strings:

```
keys, err := redis.Strings(cn.Do("KEYS", "*"))
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
for _, key := range keys {
   fmt.Println(key)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts.Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

Since Redis only has one thread, the `KEYS` command will block all other requests until it has finished, so it's not a good approach for production. Instead, use `SCAN`. [see SCAN documentation here](https://redis.io/commands/scan)

Comment: question, does the `KEYS` operation block requests to DB0, or will it block all DB requests, not just the one being queried?

As redis is single threaded, i have a feeling the answer is a yes...   `KEYS` will block requests to all DBs